# ajax, php and mysql connection issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Am fetching data from database using ajax but it is failing. The data should be displayed at the div I have declared in the main page called 'display'. The query runs but nothing is printed on the div. Here are my codes:

```
//ajax:
<script>
function Jobs(str) {

    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = 
        function  () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("POST","search.php?q="+str);

        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
//php
?php $q = intval($_GET['q']);?>

<?php

    include('includes/conn.php');
    $row="SELECT DISTINCT title,id FROM jobs  WHERE dept='$q' AND state=0 ORDER BY id";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,$row) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo $row['title'];
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: If you're using `jQuery` why not `$.ajax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample ajax example codes

addfield.php file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function Jobs(str) {

        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = 
            function  () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("POST","search.php?q="+str);

            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
    <form> 
    First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="Jobs(this.value)">
    </form>
    <p>Suggestions: <span id="display"></span></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

search.php code:

```
<?php
echo $q = $_REQUEST["q"];

?>
```

Comment: my php file is: <?php $q = intval($_GET['q']);?>

<?php

include('includes/conn.php');
$row="SELECT DISTINCT title,id FROM jobs  WHERE dept='$q' AND state=0 ORDER BY id";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$row) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
"<table>";
"<tr>";
"<th> Title</th>";
"</tr>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
"</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>

Comment: <?php 
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
include('includes/conn.php'); 
$rows ="SELECT DISTINCT title,id FROM jobs WHERE dept='$q' AND state=0 ORDER BY id"; 
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$rows) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
"<table><tr><th> Title</th></tr>"; 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>".$row['title']."</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
 } 
echo "</table>"; 
mysqli_close($conn); 
?>

Comment: It has worked.Thanks @Ramki.Error was because of 'intval'.